# Enabling Twig in Kohana3

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, twig

I have a problem with twig module for kohana3 
(this one https://github.com/jheathco/kohana-twig).

After uploading files to modules/twig, creating `cache/twig`, `views/twig` and enabling module in `bootstrap.php`, i'm getting `Internal Server Error 500` error (no matter which action/controller i'm displaying). In my apache log file i can find this error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  main(): Failed opening required ''
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /home/bajki/workspace/biospot/modules/twig/init.php on line 4

Have anyone any idea what am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does twig/init.php say on line 4? PHP can't find the file that's referenced there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was my fault - i didn't know that i need to download and install Twig class myself to vendor/Twig. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because there are some files missing; you have to clone the submodule in vendor folder, so while inside of modules/twig, do:

`git submodule update --init`

Comment: hmm i was not using git command to install my twig module. I just downloaded it from github so now i'm getting `fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent /home)` (well, i just think thats the reason)

Comment: ok nvm, i didn't knew that i need to put Twig files inside vendor subdirectory. Problem solved :)

Comment: @bajki: if my answer worked, you should close the question :)